# My Dell workstation (T7610) appears to be performing at 1/10th of expected speeds

Tags: windows, cpu, performance

I have a dell workstation T7610 with a Xeon E5-2609 CPU, running Windows 10, and it appears, via geekbench score (single core score of 250, compared to other reference systems on the internet averaging geekbench scores in the 2000-2500 range for the same CPU), to be running 10x slower than normal.

The processor tests out fine in the BIOS settings, the memory tests out fine in the BIOS memory tester.
The system RAM is DDR3 SDRAM, 4 channels.

I have searched the bios settings for any "run 10x slower" options, and can't find anything that would do this.

Normal system with similar CPU benches in at 2113 single core:
https://browser.geekbench.com/geekbench3/8865502

My system scores under 250:
https://browser.geekbench.com/v5/cpu/5725016

Any ideas?

Comment: I know nothing about Geekbench or workstations, but I find [this](http://support.primatelabs.com/kb/geekbench/frequently-asked-questions#how-do-i-compare-scores-): "Note that Geekbench 5 scores are only comparable with Geekbench 5 scores. This is also true for Geekbench 4, Geekbench 3, and Geekbench 2. Each major version of Geekbench 5 includes significant changes and upgrades, and may change the baseline for comparison, so comparing scores between them will not be accurate."

Comment: Have you checked the frequent the CPU is running at?

Comment: Yes, the bios reports correct frequency as do the geekbench reports above.

Comment: It seems like something is severely affecting memory bandwidth.

Comment: I just ran geekbench 3 & 5 on my Xeon X5690. Single core results v3 3440 v5 650. You have to compare like with like. Your score should be around 490 on v5, so yes, it's slow, but not as slow as you make out.

Comment: Okay thank you SO MUCH.   With bios tweaks I can achieve a 490 so it's within an order of magnitude of the X5690 (another 2011 era cpu). I take back what I said above. The geekbench scores are not even close from generation to generation.

Some of the performance is that the system had been running in single channel mode (memory bandwidth = 50%).

Comment: Glad you got it figured :)) You could try squeezing all this info into a  self-answer (& accept it), if only to close the loop - & in case any future Googlers may find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay three parts:

1. Mixing different Geekbench versions is of course wrong, but I didn't realize how wrong.
2. The E5-2609 CPU is notably one of the weakest ever released for this socket, if not the weakest CPU for this generation of motherboards.
3. The Memory dual channel issue was responsible for about a 30% performance hit on top.
4. Bad BIOS performance settings were another 30% performance hit.

With proper bios settings, and fully populated dual channel memory this machine performs AS EXPECTED if not stellar, at least, reasonably well.